# Is there a way to know the mysql server timezone using php?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to know the mysql server timezone using php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html):

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html)

Just wrap this in `mysql_query()`